# How can I make exe-file to write text on the command line?

Tags: java, maven, cmd, exe, launch4j

I have java console application, what writes text into command line. When I use jar-file, it works fine. But when I create exe-file and work with it, application does not write anything into command line. If I write in cmd `myapp.exe writeSomething > output.txt`, I can see output text in output.txt. What do I need to do to myapp.exe begins to write text into command line?

I am using launch4j-maven-plugin.

This is my configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>launch4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>l4j-clui</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>launch4j</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <headerType>gui</headerType>
....
```

Comment: The key here is what tool and how exactly created the exe file.

Comment: I used launch4j-maven-plugin

Comment: What can I use to exe-file can write text into cmd?

Comment: You need to make a console exe not a GUI exe.

Comment: Please show your config for launch4j, my crystal ball is currently out of use ...

Comment: Well, even after you *do* know the solution, you should leave the incorrect configuration in the question, so it is useful for the other people visiting StackOveflow. Please leave there your original wrong configuration containing `<headerType>gui</headerType>` and remove all the lines below this one. Thus the others will learn from your mistake and your question becomes useful for all.

Comment: #Honza Zidek, after EDIT I wrote how I solved the problem. Config for launch4j I wrote because #Serge Ballesta asked.

Comment: I believe that Serge Ballesta also wanted to see just the `<headerType>` parameter. And you don't have to edit the question with the solution. As I told, the questions should remain for others making the same mistakes. If you remove all the unnecessary ballast (here all the configuration after the `<headerType>`), just leave here its original `gui` value, the acceptance of my answer together with your comment below "Thank you! It works!" will navigate the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your POM-file should contain something like

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>launch4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>l4j-clui</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals><goal>launch4j</goal></goals>    
            <configuration>
                <headerType>console</headerType> 
                ....
            </configuration>
```

The line `<headerType>console</headerType>` is the crucial one.

Thus it will generate the EXE-file as a **console** application, not a GUI application.

See https://github.com/lukaszlenart/launch4j-maven-plugin for more details.

Comment: @user3186861 - my pleasure! :) Btw, for the next time - are you curious how I found the answer? I had not known *anything* about the plugin before. Here is the manual: http://bit.ly/1w9zNwg - the very first link...